# Webpack SASS vendor splitting

Tags: webpack, sass, code-splitting

i use this config for loading my styles:

```
{
  test: /\.(sc|c|sa)ss$/,
  use: [
    dev
      ? "vue-style-loader"
      : extractLoader,
    {
      loader: "css-loader",
      options: { modules: true, importLoaders: 2 },
    },
    "postcss-loader",
    "sass-loader",
  ],
}
```

and this for splitting:

```
optimization: {
concatenateModules: true,
runtimeChunk: "single",
splitChunks: {
  chunks: "all",
  maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
  minSize: 0,
  cacheGroups: {
    vendor: {
      test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
      name: module => {
        const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
        return `npm.${packageName.replace("@", "")}`;
      },
    },
  },
},
```

with this plugin:

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  filename: "css/[name].[chunkhash:7].min.css",
  chunkFilename: "css/[name].[chunkhash:7].min.css",
})
```

if I now import bootstrap inside a custom `.scss` file (to customize variables). Bootstrap is not added to my vendor css file, but my main css file. Is there any way how I can tell webpack to add the css from bootstrap to the vendor css file?